# php $_SESSION[token] change between pages

Tags: php, random, token

I am trying to generate a random token, save it to a $_SESSION variable, post it to another page and check if the posted value match the one saved in the

```
<input type="text" name="token" value="<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['token'] = time()."_".rand(1,100); echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>">
```

the above code for example generates and saves this **1655737072_96** (timestamp+2_random_digits)

when I post the form, to the another page, if I check the value stored in the $_SESSION['token'] for the match with the one posted I see this: **1655737072_91**

the first part is the same timestamp but the last two digits are different

I have the same behaviour with random_bytes() or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes for generating the token, if I save the value into the input and in the session, when I change page the value in the session changes

thanks

Comment: why  doing all those in input value ? do session start , setting all outside and just assign that to value !

Comment: generate in a db that with columns id ticket =your rand and sessionid (the current user) , output in input a given ticket column , on sent compare and on success delete from db , if that isnt right maning attack exploit etc then take the right action (even with sqlite an be done)

Answer (score 0):

You can this in the form page to create this so-called CSRF token.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["token"]=bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
//Rest of the code
echo "<input type='hidden' name='token' value='".$_SESSION["token"]."'/>";
```

On the other page (the action of the form) :

```
session_start();
if ($_REQUEST["token"]===$_SESSION["token"]) {
 echo "Token ok";
} else {
 echo "Token not ok";
}
```

If you change the token between pages, then of course it will be different.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing but the random bytes that I first get is like d87f75fae26784734174 and then when I post the form, to the other page the value in the $_SESSION['token'] changes like this ee11a53fb2a6eb53adf3

Comment: the value in the $_SESSION["token"] remain the same between pages only if I set it to a fixed value or for example a timestamp using time().

Comment: Try my code and this should work. $_SESSION["token"] remains as long as you don't edit it. If it is changed, this means some script executed before has changed it so it is a configuration issue. You need to check the token before reassignment. Are you also sure your session is maintained correctly?